# MvvmCross binding ObservableCollection<MyItem> to ObservableCollection<object>

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have made a custom view (MyCustomView), which can be used in android layout xml. When you click it, it opens a dialog (MyDialog) containing a list.

MainPageLayout -> MyCustomView -> *click* -> MyDialog

MyDialog inherits from MvxDialogFragment:

```
public class MyDialog : MvxDialogFragment
{
    public event EventHandler ItemSourceChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsSource;
        }

        set
        {
            itemsSource = value;
            if (ItemSourceChanged != null)
            {
                ItemSourceChanged.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.my_layout, container, false);
        var listview = view.FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.my_listview);
        listview.ItemsSource = ItemsSource;
        return view;
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection
    {
        get { return myCollection; }
        private set { SetProperty(ref myCollection, value); }
    }
}
```

So far, so good - This works as expected. The binding set is created in the view, and the list of the VM's "MyCollection" is displayed.

However, i would very much like to use MyDialog with additional different collections, not just `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`. To achieve this, i change the `ItemsSource` in MyDialog to be a `ObservableCollection<object>`, but this causes its setter to no longer being called (by the binding set), and as such the listview's itemSource is set to null.

How can i make MyDialog more general?

Comment: Suspect you may have done a typo somewhere? Not sure `To achieve this, i change the ItemsSource in MyDialog to be a ObservableCollection` makes sense?

Comment: Ah, yes, the generic type was getting cut off. I have changed the formatting. Im changing the collection from containing elements of "MyItem" to elements of "object". Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

public class `MyDialog<T>` would make it generic.

Example: [www.dotnetperls.com/generic](http://www.dotnetperls.com/generic)

Comment: I cannot make it generic, as i need to instantiate it from XML

Comment: You could inherit from a `BaseDialog<T>`

Comment: I could, but then i would a concrete implementation for every type that the dialog might use. The problem arises because changing the ViewModel is something i would like to avoid for this project - I cannot just make MyItem inherit from IListItem or something like that. Perhaps i could use a valueconverter to bind Collection<MyItem> to Collection<object> ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dynamic?

```
public ObservableCollection<dynamic> ItemsSource
```

I use a dynamic objects to pass objects and collections from one ViewModel to the next